# Trying to write javascript that fades in background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to teach myself javascript and I'm, apparently, not fully understanding.

What I'm trying to get is a box that when you click it, the background color changes smoothly from black to some color. To do this, I've created a function that takes an HSV value and spits out a string in the #rrggbb format. Hence, to fade in I simply walk the V value from 0 to 100 in increments of 1 using a for loop.

What I've got is a box that when you click it, it pauses and changes to the background color I'm using. I'm also logging the output and that calculates and updates once at the end with the RGB hex values.

So, clearly, I'm not understanding whatever knowledge is required to refresh the DOM at the intermediate steps. All searches I get for this come up with solutions using jQuery or the like. That's well and good, I intend to work my way through jQuery et al, but first, I'd like to get some things like this to work so that I can get a more thorough understanding of what is going on under the hood.

The code is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbzQJG

The code:

HTML:

```
<title>Color test</title>

<body>
  <div id="colorbox" onclick="javascript:fadeIn()"></div>
  <div id="console"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
  body {
    background: #000;
    color: #999;
  }

  #colorbox {
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Javascript:

```
var c = function() {
  return ({
    log: function(msg) {
      consoleDiv = document.getElementById('console');
      para = document.createElement('p');
      text = document.createTextNode(msg);
      para.appendChild(text);
      consoleDiv.appendChild(para);
    }
  });
}();

function toRGB(H, S, V) {
  S /= 100;
  V /= 100;
  var C = V * S;
  H /= 60;
  var X = C * (1 - Math.abs((H % 2) - 1));
  var R = 0;
  var G = 0;
  var B = 0;
  if (0 <= H && H < 1) {
    R = C;
    G = X;
    B = 0;
  } else if (1 <= H && H < 2) {
    R = X;
    G = C;
    B = 0;
  } else if (2 <= H && H < 3) {
    R = 0;
    G = C;
    B = X;
  } else if (3 <= H && H < 4) {
    R = 0;
    G = X;
    B = C;
  } else if (4 <= H && H < 5) {
    R = X;
    G = 0;
    B = C;
  } else if (5 <= H && H < 6) {
    R = C;
    G = 0;
    B = X;
  } else {
    R = 0;
    G = 0;
    B = 0;
  }

  var m = V - C;
  R = Math.round(255 * (R + m)).toString(16);
  R.length < 2 ? R = "0" + R : R = "" + R;
  G = Math.round(255 * (G + m)).toString(16);
  G.length < 2 ? G = "0" + G : G = "" + G;
  B = Math.round(255 * (B + m)).toString(16);
  B.length < 2 ? B = "0" + B : B = "" + B;

  var RGB = "#" + R + G + B;
  return RGB;
}

function pause(milliseconds) {
  var dt = new Date();
  while ((new Date()) - dt <= milliseconds) { /* Do nothing */ }
}

function fadeIn() {
  var colorbox = document.querySelector("#colorbox");
  for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    colorbox.style.backgroundColor = toRGB(150, 80, i);
    c.log(toRGB(150, 80, i));
    pause(10);
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why you want to invent the wheel new. There is a perfect function in the Jquery UI Library doing this for you https://jqueryui.com/animate/

Comment: @mimo - that's not a good advice. there are plenty reasons not to use jQuery, and it's actually getting more & more common to use [vanilla js](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Comment: @mimo Thanks for the jquery link. I'm trying to reinvent the wheel only so I can learn how it works. I don't necessarily intend to use this to implement anything other than an example. I was hoping my writeup at the top would prevent this kind of non-answer. I suppose I should put that disclaimer in a more prevalent location in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with understanding the flow of events in a browser (and JS in general). (Standard) JavaScript works as a single-threaded asynchronous process. As such, for anything to happen "in between" your code, you need to somehow return execution to the calling context. That's true when nested inside a call stack within JavaScript code as well as when you want to "see" the effect of your code on the browser window.

Your problem is that `pause` isn't pausing anything. It busy-waits. You need to return control to the browser.

You could achieve your goal like this:

```
function fadeIn() {
  var colorbox = document.querySelector("#colorbox");

  var i = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(i > 100) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      return;
    }
    colorbox.style.backgroundColor = toRGB(150, 80, i);
    c.log(toRGB(150, 80, i));
    i++
  }, 10);
}
```

`pause` is not needed in this solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to learn. Thanks! The flow of events plus the fact that the browser includes a built-in scheduler was invaluable and has sent me down the path of further understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your pass function keeps the processor busy. Because JavaScript is single threaded and event based, the DOM is not updated while your code is running. By using `setTimeout` to pause execution instead of your busy loop, you can make the DOM update between your changes, thereby displaying your fading effect.

The code for the `fadeIn` would look like this in this case:

```
function fadeIn(i) {
  if (i >= 100) {return;}
  var colorbox = document.querySelector("#colorbox");
  colorbox.style.backgroundColor = toRGB(150, 80, i);
  c.log(toRGB(150, 80, i));
  setTimeout(function(){fadeIn(i + 1);},10);
}
```

Your HTML call should be `fadeIn(0)` with this code.

A bit more extensive explanation on the single threaded model of JavaScript can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5992511/2041231) answer.

A forked, improved, version of your codepen of your code is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbzQPd).

Comment: This is a great solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating it. You should use CSS transitions and just add/remove a class. So for your `#colorbox` you should add the `transition` property:

```
#colorbox {
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

Then let's say you have a class `.new-bckgr`:

```
.new-bckgr {
    background: #76430; /* or whatever colour you want */
}
```

Now all you need to do is something like this:

```
$("#colorbox").on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('new-backgr');
});
```

And you it will smoothly fade from black to what colour you put in the `.new-bckgr` class. And if you remove the class, it will **fade** back **to black**.

Comment: If you don't like to use another class for the new colour, you can just change the css with `.css()` http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: That's an ok solution to get the fade working, but it does so without meaningful javascript. OP wants to learn javascript and is struggling with that, not with CSS/DOM/Effects.

Comment: @Lucian, this isn't helpful for the goal I'm trying to accomplish, learning javascript.